# Problems while deploying application in Tomcat 6.0.x

Tags: tomcat6

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name......

I got the above problem while deploying my project in Tomcat .
I got another problem : Unable to initialize the bean Configurator.jar 
Do the above problems are occurring due to environmental settings or Project specific problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like its a spring encounters some error during the war startup.
Usually spring gets triggered as a context listener and it starts to initialize your beans and resolve dependencies between the beans. There is one certain bean that fails (Configurator I guess) and the whole spring initialization process fails because of that.

You can debug the bean initialization code (probably constructor) and try to understand why does spring fail to initialize it properly. In any case I can't give you more information without a full stacktrace.

Hope this helps